# It has more to do with that I am lazy than that I am tired

Tags: grammar, usage

Are all these sentences below correct and interchangeable?

> 1) It has more to do with **that** I am lazy than **that** I am tired.
>
> 2) It has more to do with **the fact that** I am lazy than **that** I am tired.
>
> 3) It has more to do with **the fact that** I am lazy than **the fact that** I am tired.
>
> 4) It has more to do with **that** I am lazy rather than **that** I am tired.
>
> 5) It has more to do with **the fact that** I am lazy rather than **that** I am tired.
>
> 6) It has more to do with **the fact that** I am lazy rather than **the fact that** I am tired.

(4. 5. and the 6. sentences are the same as the first three sentences except that I changed "than" to "rather than")

One more question: Are these sentences correct and interchangeable?

> 7) It has to do with **the fact that** I am lazy rather than **that** I am tired.
>
> 8) It has to do with **that** I am lazy rather than **that** I am tired.

*My opinion on these eight sentences:* I guess I have to use the phrase **"the fact that"** after the word **"with"**, but I think I can use the word **"that"** after **"than"**, and I guess it is better to use **"that"** after **"than"** or **"rather than"** instead of using **"the fact that"**. Also I think **"rather than"** and **"than"** are interchangeable in the first six sentences I gave.  What do you think?

Comment: 7 and 8 lack a comparative.   (**more** with X **than** with Y)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Isn't "rather than" some flavor of *comparative*?

Comment: @Andrew; You are right, of course. For some reason, my brain didn't see **rather** in the second clause. I think after reading 1-6, a rut had been cut in the gray matter :)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thanks. Do you think all those sentences are correct? Can I use **"that"** after **"with"** there?

Comment: Yes, **the fact that** and **that** are interchangeable, although some speakers would feel that **the fact that** is the more natural or conversational of the two. To my ear, the register of "has to do with the fact that I am lazy" is consistent, whereas "has to do with that I am lazy" seems to combine a conversational register and a somewhat more formal register. There's a slight "hiccup".  *That there is a slight register hiccup may be of no concern to you.*  :-)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thanks again.You mean that they are interchangeable in the sentence I gave, right? Because as far as I know they are not always interchangeable. In some cases we have to use **"the fact that"** instead of **"that"**. For example we can not say **"I like him despite that he is a jerk sometimes"**. We have to say **"I like him despite the fact that he is a jerk sometimes"**

Comment: @Fire and Ice: There's nothing inherently wrong with **despite that he's a jerk sometimes**.  **the fact** might be more frequent, but its absence there is not ungrammatical. https://books.google.com/books?id=ppxxCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA276&lpg=PA276&dq=%22despite+that+he%22&source=bl&ots=yJgA_PmGdp&sig=3svoizPPjT8nGHhG5PmwVY6HQcA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicu_bln_nbAhUy0FkKHeNHBCUQ6AEIZzAI#v=onepage&q=%22despite%20that%20he%22&f=false

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I today opened this topic: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170709/there-is-nothing-with-that-you-are-fat/170713?noredirect=1#comment341412_170713 A native speaker told me it was wrong to say that sentence I gave on that page with **"that"**. So, you don't agree with him? Are you a native English speaker as well?

Comment: @Fire and Ice: Yes, I am a native speaker. Most native speakers would say **despite the fact that he is ...**, but *as the book I cited above indicates*, some do say **despite that he's**.

Answer (score 1):

They're all fine as written.  Some are more *wordy* than others, but that might be something you want, in the right context.

There's not much more to say, so instead here are some other options:

> It is more (the fact) that I am lazy than that I am tired.
>
> It has more to do with laziness than tiredness.
>
> It is more laziness than tiredness.
>
> I'm more lazy than tired.

I don't really like "tiredness".  Sure, it's in the dictionary but in my opinion it's clunky.  "Weariness" is a little better, if you want to keep the "-ness" alliteration:

> It is more laziness than weariness.

Or you can repeat the "L" sound:

> It is more laziness than lassitude.

You do have to be careful with alliteration.  Because it's such an obvious literary affectation, it can sound *forced* rather than elegant.  It may be better style to just use two different nouns:

> It is more lethargy than fatigue.

Comment: You don't have to use "fact".  It's just a common expression.  In my opinion all of those expressions are too wordy, and a good writer should go with something more succinct.  But that's all personal preference.

Comment: By "you don't have to use 'fact'", you mean I don't have to use it after **"with"**, right? As far as I know, in the sentences like "Because of the fact that he is a good person, he is always losing" or "Despite the fact that I love cola, I won't drink it anymore", we can't replace "the fact that" with "that".

Comment: Can you also please look at this question I asked which has to do with this topic? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170709/there-is-nothing-with-that-you-are-fat/170716?noredirect=1#comment341373_170716

Comment: @FireandIce  *"because of the fact that ..."* is the same as *"because ..."*.  It's redundant, but nevertheless a natural English expression.  There's really not much more to say about this phrase.

Comment: Yeah. I know that it is the same as "because". We can't say "because of that" instead of it though.