# There is nothing with that you are fat

Tags: grammar, usage

Are these two sentences interchangeable?

> There is nothing wrong with that you are fat.
>
> There is nothing wrong with the fact that you are fat.

Answer (score 2):

In English, when you use *nothing wrong with*, you follow it with a noun. This noun can be an **object** or a **gerund** (a form of a verb that acts like a noun). Look at the following two sentences.

> There is nothing wrong with ***the food***. (object)
>
> There is nothing wrong with ***eating*** *the food*. (gerund)

They both mean two different things:

- The sentence with the object (*food*) means *there are no problems with the food*, or, quite simply, *the food isn't bad*.
- The sentence with the gerund (*eating*) means *there is no problem with **the action of eating** the food*, or, quite simply, ***the action of eating the food*** isn't bad.

---

Using this information, we examine the first sentence.

> There is nothing wrong with that you are fat.

This is **incorrect** because *that*, in this case, is a **conjunction** and not a noun.

The word *that* can also act like a pronoun, however, and if you were to just say

> There is nothing wrong with **that**.

you would be correct, because it is referring to an unknown thing (object/action/state).

If you want to fix this sentence, you could say

> There is nothing wrong with **fatness**. (I prefer *obesity*)
>
> There is nothing wrong with **being fat**.

---

The second sentence is **correct** because it is referring to the noun ***fact***.

One thing I would mention is that you shouldn't use it in direct conversation with somebody else for two reasons:

1. It's always good to be courteous, and talking about the obesity of someone doesn't make them happy.
2. Stating that their obesity is a *fact* may not make them too happy either.

---

To answer your question: are the sentences interchangeable?

Most definitely **not**.

The first sentence is also incorrect, so don't use it.

Comment: In this topic I very recently opened (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170670/it-has-more-to-do-with-that-i-am-lazy-than-that-i-am-tired/170677?noredirect=1#comment341356_170677), Andrew told me that I could use **"that"** after **"with"**. Do you agree with him? If you do, why can't I use **"that"** here while I can use it there? Also, are you a native English speaker? Just wondering. :)

Comment: @FireandIce Your only problem is that you are adding subordinate clauses to the word _that_ (which, as I said, is fine by itself in this case) which is making your sentence incorrect. I am a native speaker, and as such I can quickly think of many sentences that go against this "rule" (from what I see, that's not what he said), such as "He is going to the park with _that you are fat_".

Comment: Thanks again. So you say I can't say **"that"** after **"with"** in those sentences I gave on that page either?

Comment: @FireandIce That takes a whole other answer, something that was already given by others. Don't forget: you asked about using it with **_nothing wrong with_**, not with the sentences you made in another post. People answering your question only use **what you've given us in the question**, not what you've stated in other questions (unless you mention that in your question).

Comment: I can't see the difference between "to do with" and "wrong with".

Comment: @FireandIce I'm trying to help you, but you're extrapolating in a way that prompts you to write another question based on this topic. All I will say is this: they are different because [_do with_](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/do-with) is a phrasal verb. _Nothing wrong with_ means "having no problems". Don't assume that they're the same because they have _with_, because they aren't. Anyway, if that didn't answer your question, please make a question based on the difference between using _that_ with _to do with_ and _that_ with _nothing wrong with_.